# Mathematical Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

1 * 1 = 1

2 * 13 = 2

3 * 3 = 3

44 * 8 = 4

73 * 5 = 0

90 * 60 = 0

Q1) What is the smallest set of numbers under this operation that can equal 5? 6?

Q2) What is 8 * 9?

Hint:

> The operation is commutative, but not associative.

Comment: Can you clarify what Q1 means, please? It's a binary operation but the phrasing of the question makes it seem as though you can interpret it as a single-valued function. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet the commutativity requirement I can make the answers to Q1

> $0$ and $0$

using

> $$L*R=\min(L\pmod{20}, R\pmod{20})\pmod{5}$$

in which case $8*9$ is

> $3$

Note that the function is not associative, for example $(1*5)*5 \neq 1*(5*5)$

---

Previous answer:

I can make the answers to Q1

> $0$ and $0$

using

> $$L*R = \begin{cases} L\pmod5 & \text{if $L\pmod{5} \in \{1,2,4\}$} \\ R\pmod5 & \text{if $L\pmod{5} \in \{0,3\}$} \\ \end{cases}$$

in which case $8*9$ is

> $4$

Comment: It does have something to do with modulo 5, but not to do with the numbers on the left or right hand side. 

And 8*9 is not equal to 4.

Comment: The question asked to make the number of answers that are $5$ and then $6$ as small as possible and then to give $8*9$, this makes both as small as possible and then evaluates $8*9$ using the function I provided, so why is it not correct?

Comment: I am looking for a specific operation.

Comment: Then you need to reword your puzzle - I see you now added a hint which rules out this answer, but does it rule out all possible answers except the one you have in mind?

Comment: I find this no different than a riddle, which may also have possible answers.

Comment: Such puzzles are usually closed as "too broad".

Comment: There are more often than not several answers to a riddle. Such is the way of the English language.

Comment: I updated to add a new answer that meets your new requirement.